# cdo mail with .xlsm attachment - receivers cannot enable macros

Tags: excel, vba, cdo.message

I'm currently automating Excel to send an email with .xlsm attachment to users that contains vba within the workbook.  When they try to open the file, they are receiving the following pop-up:  "BLOCKED CONTENT"  Macros in this document have been disabled by your enterprise administrator for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

That is because the company that receives your `.xlsm` file does not allow macros/VBA in their company (which is a very good decision actually). There is nothing *you* can do about it, as it is the rules/policy of that company and not your decision.

Note that most companys disallow macros from outside the company (and that **every** company should do that).